# G++ Compiling Visual Studio Code

Tags: build, g++, visual-studio-code

I have installed Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu, but I can't seem to get it to compile. I have looked at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp and https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks and have tried all the examples but I keep getting the error "No build task defined. Mark a task with 'isBuildCommand' in the tasks.json file." The command I would like to run is `g++ Main.cpp Classes.cpp -o Planets -lGL -lglut`

Answer (score 0):

I once encountered this problem. What I learned from that are these:

1. Make sure your `Main.cpp`, `Classes.cpp` are at the `$workspaceRoot` or use relative path.
2. Make sure your tasks.json file does not contain any error.
3. Make sure the tasks.json has a version number at the top of the code.
4. Make sure the type of the task is correct. (e.g. For a console app, it should be `"shell"`)

I have created a tasks.json file for you. It works with my Main.cpp(put a Hello world program in it) and Classes.cpp(A simple class). Compare yours to mine to see if you did something wrong.

```
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "taskName": "Build",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "g++",
        "args": [
            "Main.cpp", 
            "Classes.cpp",
            "-o", 
            "Planets", 
            "-lGL", 
            "-lglut"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "problemMatcher": []
    }
]
}
```